# Firebase.database() fails after app timeout or going in background in react-native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

I noticed that sometimes in my app it fails to fetch any data when using `firebase.database()` while `firebase.auth()` works fine and user is authenticated already signed in. Restarting the app will make it fetch data fine but this is going to be a problem for the user. This happens too when doing reload in react-native while debugging. This behavior happens in both Android and iOS.

How can I solve this problem or what could I have done wrong?

Code I am using for fetching my data:

```
 componentDidMount() {
    this.autoFetchContacts()
  }

autoFetchContacts = async () => {
    let contacts = []
    let currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser
    if(currentUser) {
      let userUID = currentUser.uid
      await firebase.database().ref().child("registered_contacts").orderByChild("uid").equalTo(userUID).on("value", async (usersSnaps) => {
        console.log("UsersSnaps: ", usersSnaps)
        usersSnaps.forEach(async userSnap => {
            await userSnap.child("contacts").ref.once("value").then((contactsSnaps) => {
              contactsSnaps.forEach(contactSnap => {
                let contact = contactSnap.val()
                console.log("contact: ", contact)
                contact["key"] = contactSnap.key
                contacts.push(contact)
              })
              contacts = this.filter(contacts, this.state.searchText)
              console.log("Filtered contacts: ", contacts)
              this.setState({contacts: contacts})
            })
          })
        })
    }

  }
```

The code line is not being outputted unless I restart app:

```
console.log("UsersSnaps: ", usersSnaps)
```

Comment: Can you please include relevant code?

Comment: code that I am using for fetching data?